# Adding elements to fragment_main.xml does noting

Tags: android, android-fragments

I added EditText and Button tags to the fragments_main.xml.
But it doesn't show a text field and button when i run the application.
However when i add the EditText and Button to activity_main.xml then it works fine. Please help. I have ADT v22.2.1-833290
Here is the activity_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the fragment_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the MainActivity Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Plz post your `activity_main.xml` file and the code for `MainActivity`

Comment: You don't seem to be using your fragment anywhere.

Comment: In `MainActivity` only the `activity_main.xml` is loaded. Therefore, only the content of `activity_main.xml` is displayed in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you load the fragment_main.xml in your code?

Typically, an Activity should load a Fragment and the Fragment should load the xml file that you just mentioned.

In the above code, you are only loading the `activity_main.xml` file in the `MainActivity`. Therefore, only the content of `activity_main.xml` is displayed in the view.

**UPDATE**

To load the `fragment_main` XML file, you can either:

- Replace the line of code in `MainActivity` from `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);`
- OR, create a class extending `Fragment` in the `MainActivity` and let that class load the `fragment_main` XML.

To do the latter, you can follow the step by step guide here: [Fragments | Adding a UI](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#UI)

In essence, Create a class:

```
public static class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

And load the created `Fragment` class in your `MainActivity` ([Fragments | Adding a Fragment to an Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)).

To load, you can either declare the fragment inside the `activity_main.xml` layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.ui.ExampleFragment"
            android:id="@+id/example_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Or try the answer mustafa gave.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So how do i load the fragment_main.xml?

Comment: I updated my answer above to describe how to load the `fragment_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);

        setContentView(frame, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(newFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

ExampleFragment.java

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment {
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main.xml, container, false);

return view;
            }
        }
```