# How to add ListView to fragment_main.xml

Tags: java, android, listview, fragment, navigation-drawer

I know this is simple question. And I will lose reputations for this question as well. But I am struggling to sort this out. I have created android project with DrawerNavigationLayout. But I have hard time adding simple ListView to the layout.

Here are my layout files.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.andromedatech.musicupv2.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#04330000"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/song_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my **MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        songView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);
        songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

        getSongList();

        Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
            public int compare(Song a, Song b){
                return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
            }
        });

        SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(this, songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

    }
```

And it issues NullPointerException due to **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** does not containing ListView. But the problem is how to implement Listview without losing NavigationDrawerLayout. I understand this would be possible duplicate to some previous posts. But I don't understand how to implement it.

I tried to setContentView to fragment_main but it didn't work out.

Reference - [Adding elements to fragment_main.xml does noting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548447/adding-elements-to-fragment-main-xml-does-noting)

Comment: I would vote your question back up if I could but I'm out of votes for today. Hopefully, my answer will make up for it ;) Let me know if there's something that you need me to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`songView` will always be null because by doing `songView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);` in your Activity, you are actually looking for the ListView inside the View hierarchy of `activity_main.xml`, and it's not there.

In order to solve this, you would need to move the code for the `ListView` inside your Fragment's code. Something like this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    songView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.song_list);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    songList = new ArrayList<Song>();

    getSongList();

    Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>(){
        public int compare(Song a, Song b){
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

    // Note that I removed 'this' (referring to the Activity) from the adapter's constructor since we are now in a Fragment.
    //and replaced it with getActivity()
    SongAdapter songAdt = new SongAdapter(getActivity(), songList);
    songView.setAdapter(songAdt);
```

Another problem is that you're not adding your `Fragment` to the Activity's layout anywhere. One way of doing it, since you seem to already have a container for it, would be to do something like this in your `onCreate` method in your `Activity`:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
// This is assuming you're using classes from teh support lib, of course.
// Retrieve the appropriate FragmentManager according to the super class of your Activity
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new MainFragment());
// MainFragment is the fragment that contains the ListView
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But still I get one error on  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

Comment: @MD can you be more specific ? I might have missed something but I can't see it :)

Comment: @2Dee Here it is  `songView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.song_list);`

Comment: @MD Nice catch, you da real MVP, I stand corrected, I edited the answer with your correction :)

Comment: @2Dee +1 deserving. where are you now days? i haven't see you in `G+`

Comment: @Isuru did you remember to place that code inside your Fragment code ? That error means that onActivityCreated is not a method of the class it was declared in, so you probably left that code in your Activity. I recommend you [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) and [this page](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) to learn more about Fragments,, hopefully, it will make things clearer.